# Why product array is not displaying all elements while using state from useSelector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Here, the product is not showing all elements from the array. This is Home Code.

I made a schema of products now I made a reducer.js file in which I assigned `products=> array` now this fetch details from `productAction.js`  everything works correctly and shows `product[0]` as a result but after applying map function in `home.js` `product[1]-product[10]` does not show up on screen.

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { CgMouse } from "react-icons/cg";
import "./Home.css";
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard.js";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import { clearErrors, getProduct } from "../../actions/productAction";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";

const Home = () => {
  const alert = useAlert();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { loading, error, products } = useSelector((state) => state.products);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
    dispatch(getProduct());
  }, [dispatch, error, alert]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <MetaData title="eDavaa" />

          <div className="banner">
            <p> </p>
            <h1> </h1>

            <a href="#container">
              <button>
                Scroll <CgMouse />
              </button>
            </a>
          </div>

          <h2 className="homeHeading">Featured Products</h2>

          <div className="container" id="container">
            {products &&
              products.map((product) => (
                <ProductCard key={product._id} product={product} />
              ))}
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here is Product Reducer Code

```
export const productsReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST:
        case ADMIN_PRODUCT_REQUEST:
            return {
                loading: true,
                products: [],
            };
        case ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                products: action.payload.products,
                productsCount: action.payload.productsCount,
                resultPerPage: action.payload.resultPerPage,
                filteredProductsCount: action.payload.filteredProductsCount,
            };

        case ADMIN_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                products: action.payload,
            };
        case ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL:
        case ADMIN_PRODUCT_FAIL:
            return {
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload,
            };

        case CLEAR_ERRORS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

and Here is backend code ->

```
exports.getAllProducts = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res) => {

    const resultPerPage = 8;
    const productsCount = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

    const apiFeature = new ApiFeatures(Product.find(), req.query).search().filter().pagination(resultPerPage);
    const products = await apiFeature.query;
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        products,
        productsCount
    });
})
```

Here is product action code

```
// Get All Products
export const getProduct =
  (keyword = "", currentPage = 1, price = [0, 25000], category, ratings = 0) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST });

      let link = `/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}&price[gte]=${price[0]}&price[lte]=${price[1]}&ratings[gte]=${ratings}`;

      if (category) {
        link = `/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}&price[gte]=${price[0]}&price[lte]=${price[1]}&category=${category}&ratings[gte]=${ratings}`;
      }

      const { data } = await axios.get(link);

      dispatch({
        type: ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
        payload: error.response.data.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

Product Showing only one element that is product[0]? What should I Do.

I tried everything. But still no solution.

Comment: if you add a log right after calling the selector: 

`const { loading, error, products } = useSelector((state) => state.products);`

`console.log({products});`

are you seeing the array of products you are expecting?

Comment: It is only showing one element in product array i.e product[0].

Comment: And if you inspect your request to the server on devtools the network tab? Do you see more elements on the products array?

Comment: No. I only see first element . But in postman after get request all products are displayed . But in front it only fetch 1st product.

Comment: Are you sure your postman request and your client request are exactly identical? 
Do they have the exact same payload? Check the request payload on the devtools network tab to make sure.

Comment: Yes They have exactly same payload request

Comment: Strange, what about the URL? Anyway, it seems like this isn't a React issue but some issue with your request to the server.

Comment: I got the error  It is in this line here due to this its not showing all products but i dont know how to correct it. ===> let link = `/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}&price[gte]=${price[0]}&price[lte]=${price[1]}&ratings[gte]=${ratings}`;

Comment: Also I made a different URL for all products that will filter according to category etc but It is also showing no products. The problem is in URL

Comment: Hey @HatimNalwala I think your problem is in url